# Resizing and HTML Video

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video

```
<!-- Header -->
<header id="top">

    <video autoplay loop poster="towkio.png" style="height:675px; width:100%" id="bgvid">

<source src="towkio.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

```
        <span id="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png">
        </span>

</header>
```

I would like to make the height 675px, and still have it span the full width it acts quite weird.

http://shearelegancechicago.com/todd/

Comment: Can you explain more correctly what you want?

Comment: http://shearelegancechicago.com/todd/example.png the video should have a size of 675 and fill the whole container. the "video" is that picture of the city

Comment: there's page not found

Comment: sorry i put the wrong link

Comment: understood, working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```css
#video-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#video-bg > video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 635px;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #video-bg > video {
      height: 300%;
      top: -100%;
  }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #video-bg > video {
      width: 300%;
      left: -100%;
  }
}

@supports (object-fit: cover) {
  #video-bg > video {
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 635px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}

#logo img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header id="video-bg">
    <video autoplay loop poster="towkio.png" id="bgvid">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</header>
<span id="logo">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Vanamo_Logo.png">
</span>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wf9pymvj/5) is live demo.
[Source](http://fvsch.com/code/video-background). I just changed height of video, and that added logo with help of `z-index`.

Comment: So close. Just gotta figure out how to push the the the sections down.

Comment: @VeliborNikolic do you want to push video to bottom?

Comment: http://shearelegancechicago.com/todd/ move the work section under the video section and maybe fix the height of the containter

Comment: @VeliborNikolic to `#video-bg` apply `position: absolute` instead `position: fixed`. Than play with margins in work and contact sections.

Comment: so close. just the video covers the logo and the nav drawer now. z-index seems to not help

Comment: @VeliborNikolic `z-index` works just with `position: absolute` on both elements

Comment: @VeliborNikolic set `z-index: -1;` to #video-bg, then set margin-top: 400px and also set to other elements margin. Everything works fine!

Comment: video still covers logo and navbox even though its zindex is 2000 and the others are one

Comment: @VeliborNikolic I sad set `z-index` to `-1` value;